# I'm trying to give user posibility to upload picture from blog-page, but I'm stucked at 'models' file

Tags: django, model, request, nameerror

It says:
**form_class = PostForm(request.FILES or None) NameError: name 'request' is not defined**

Comment: post your complete view code

Comment: form_class should be the class. Don't instantiate it. So form_class = PostForm

Answer (score 0):

```
from django.http import HttpResponse, HttpResponseRedirect
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.views.generic import ListView, DetailView, CreateView, UpdateView, DeleteView
from . models import Post
from . forms import PostForm
from django.urls import reverse_lazy

class HomeView(ListView):
    model = Post
    template_name = 'home.html'
    ordering = ['-id']

class articleDetailView(DetailView):
    model = Post
    template_name = 'article_details.html'

class AddPostView(CreateView):
    model = Post
    form_class = PostForm(request.FILES or None)
    template_name = 'add_post.html'

class UpdatePostView(UpdateView):
    model = Post
    form_class = PostForm(request.FILES or None)
    template_name = 'update_post.html' 

class DeletePostView(DeleteView):
    model = Post
    template_name = 'delete_post.html'
    success_url = reverse_lazy('home')
```

Comment: This code should be in your question, not as an answer (unless this is, indeed, your working code and you've solved your problem).